# use ESC key to enter fullscreen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fullscreen

all keys can be used to enter fullscreen but seems like not the ESC one (It enters fullscreen but exits it immediately after, seems like preventDefault isn't helping)б any ideas?

```
function onkeydownP(b) 
{
    switch (b.keyCode) 
    {
    case 27: // KeyEvent.DOM_VK_ESC
        var el = document.documentElement
        var rfs = el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen || el.mozRequestFullScreen;
        rfs.call(el);
        b.preventDefault();
        break;
    }
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", onkeydownP, true);
```

EDIT: Fixed keycode in code to right one

Comment: `13` is return key, escape is `27` I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the event key to 27 (ESC). A helpful resource http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Also, you're missing a semicolon at the end of your `el` declaration. Change your code to:

```
function onkeydownP(b) 
{
    switch (b.keyCode) 
    {
    case KeyEvent.DOM_VK_DOWN:
        var el = document.documentElement;
        var rfs = (el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen || el.mozRequestFullScreen);
        rfs.call(el);
        cancelEvent(b);
        break;
    case 27: // KeyEvent.DOM_VK_ESC
        var el = document.documentElement;
        var rfs = (el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen || el.mozRequestFullScreen);
        rfs.call(el);
        b.preventDefault();
        cancelEvent(b);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try it out in a fiddle but it's down: http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/jsfiddle.net.html

Comment: It enters fullscreen with these fixed but exits it immediately after, seems like preventDefault isn't helping

Comment: What if you try to bind it to onKeyup instead? Maybe the browser's default action to leave full screen is bound to the keyup event? If you preventDefault on that action, it should probably work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This saved me a lot of trouble. I was wondering why you couldn't `e.preventDefault` escape when doing `keydown`. Using `keyup` did the trick.